# prevent rounding off values in primefaces inputnumber

Tags: jsf, primefaces

how can i prevent primefaces input number from rounding-off values?

Comment: Why do you think it does round of a number? And how do you know that is not what you tell it to do? PF showcase shows a great working example where it does not round things off: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputNumber.xhtml

Comment: Any feedback???